# How to write my own select method for selecting any variables from any dataset by their names, without using dplyr

Tags: r, function

Help to write my own select method for selecting any variables from any dataset by their names,
without using dplyr. How to correctly specify method argument for choosing variables?
It works in one line `df[, c('year', 'month')]`, but not in a function.

```
select <- function(dataset, vars) {
  dataset[, c(vars)]
}
select(df, 'year', 'month')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified more arguments that the fcuntion expected. Just wrap your column names in a vector `c()` and pass it to the function.

```
select_func <- function(dataset, vars) {
      dataset[vars] # or dataset[, vars]
    }
    select_func(iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Species"))
```